# How does adding more consumers increase kafka processing scalability

Tags: apache-kafka

Assumption:  My code uses the fan out model (single partition multiple consumers)

The producer inserts messages M1-M10 into kafka

I start consumer 1 (C1), it begins processing messages.  At the point where it is on M3 I start a second consumer.

Consumer 2 (C2) now starts processing M1 then moves to the next message.  Meanwhile C1 continues.

So C1 always leads C2, C2 is just reprocessing the same messages that C1 has already worked through.

So adding more consumers does nothing to help with scalability, or so it would seem.  I must be misunderstanding the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So adding more consumers does nothing to help with scalability

That is correct. If you have multiple consumers reading from the same partition, you will not achieve any parallelism.

The unit of scaling in Kafka is the partition:

> The partitions in the log serve several purposes. First, they allow the log to scale beyond a size that will fit on a single server. Each individual partition must fit on the servers that host it, but a topic may have many partitions so it can handle an arbitrary amount of data. Second they act as the unit of parallelism—more on that in a bit. — [Documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_topics)

So in order to scale the situation you describe, you must partition the topic your consumers are reading. Then, when you can add consumers you can achieve parallelism.